# Error:(1) Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.tk2323.ftsm.lab_ui_intent_a160158.MainActivity">
```

please help me this is the first time im using android studio and i have 3 errors and it said about xml. I'm not really sure about this.......

```
 Error:(1) Error parsing XML: XML declaration not well-formed
```

Comment: This is the entire xml file already?

Comment: Where is `</LinearLayout>`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a tutorial service. Please read up on the very basics of the technologies you are using and come back when you understand what you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [XML specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) you're missing a whitespace, it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: omg thank you it worked!!!